# call webservice and use Mage::getStoreConfig - Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am creating a custom magento module and I am adding a license check. 
The webservice is in place and I am now testing it.

I am trying to use the Mage::getStoreConfig to get the saved license code but I always get below error.

I think the problem is that I am just testing and having a php file in the root of magento and he doesn't connect / know the path to app/mage but I have no clue anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the top of your php code add

```
<?php 
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
```

See [Run Code Externally](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/run-magento-code-externally/)